# Gitea cannot push due do ssl error message tlsv1 alert protocol version

Tags: git, macos, ssl, gitea

I have installed gitea in my server. I created a first repository and checked it out.

So far everything works.

Now i want to push something to gitea and get the following error message:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitea.XXX.com/XX/XXX.git/': error:1400442E:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol versio
```

I am using MacOS 10.15.6 and git version is: git version 2.24.1 (Apple Git-126)

any idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks and kind regards

solick

Comment: Did you check the TLS version on your server  and also your in Mac ? your mac's TLS version should be less than or equal to TLS version on your server

Comment: @rootkonda my server use tls 1.3 so there should be no problem at all

Comment: Please try updating the openssl in your mac and then retry

Comment: I use homebrew and already have the newest version.

Comment: Maybe you have to configure your git settings: `git config --global --add http.sslVersion tlsv1.3`

Comment: no it seams there is a problem with the Nginx proxy config which allows only tlsv1.3